# onperformsync and multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, android-syncadapter

I am doing my network operations inside the onPerformSync method of AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter. 
I want to know if these operations will run on a separate thread by default when my application is running in foreground, backround and dead. 
If no (for any case), please tell me the best approach for running it on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html), an `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter` is 
**An abstract implementation of a SyncAdapter that spawns a thread to invoke a sync operation.**

> I want to know if these operations will run on a separate thread by
>   default when my application is running in foreground, backround and
>   dead.

It spawns a separate thread for your sync operations regardless of your applications state, so it's safe to do your network operations in `onPerformSync` without creating your own threads